# Change AWK command to "Grep -v"

Tags: unix, awk, grep

Is there an easy fix to this command, changing it from outputting everything that matches, to outputting everything that DONT match?

```
    awk            'FILENAME=="/Users/RNAseq/Transcriptomic_results/8_DEseq2/1_Results/StatusResults_sign_DESeq2.csv"{A[$1]=$1}
FILENAME=="/Users/RNAseq/Transcriptomic_results/9_EdgeR/1_Results/StatusResults_edgeR_sign.csv"{if(A[$1]){print$1}}' 
/Users/sindrelee/RNAseq/Transcriptomic_results/8_DEseq2/1_Results/StatusResults_sign_DESeq2.csv 
/Users/RNAseq/Transcriptomic_results/9_EdgeR/1_Results/StatusResults_edgeR_sign.csv > 
/Users/RNAseq/Transcriptomic_results/DESeqvsedgeR_status.csv
```

Comment: So changing `if(A[$1])` to `if(!A[$1])` doesn't work?

Comment: Ah, thats what I was looking for.. Sry, totally command-line idiot.. Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion - make the question as short as possible. There is a lot of cruft here... `awk 'FILENAME=="myFile" ...` etc will immediately make it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to investigate using a more appropriate tool such as the `join` utility - see also [join(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join).  In particular, something like:

```
join -t, -v 2 StatusResults_sign_DESeq2.csv StatusResults_edgeR_sign.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

try find command with -not option